# Knowing the parameter name for a call to an entrypoint with Beacon

Tags: transactions, dapps, parameter, beacon

I would like to call the *stake* entry point of a Plenty contract. I only have access to the Michelson [source code](https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1QqjR4Fj9YegB37PQEqXUPHmFbhz6VJtwE/code).

Here is my [current non-working code](https://docs.walletbeacon.io/playground?code=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) in Typescript with Beacon-SDK (inspired by [this example](https://docs.walletbeacon.io/playground/?code=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)).

> ```
> import { DAppClient, TezosOperationType } from "@airgap/beacon-sdk";    
>
> const PLENTYtoPLENTY = 'KT1QqjR4Fj9YegB37PQEqXUPHmFbhz6VJtwE'
> const dAppClient = new DAppClient({ name: 'Plenty staker' })
>
> const activeAccount = await dAppClient.getActiveAccount()
> if (!activeAccount) {
>     const permissions = await dAppClient.requestPermissions()
> }
>
> const ops = new Array(1).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
>   return {
>     kind: TezosOperationType.TRANSACTION,
>     amount: "0",
>     destination: PLENTYtoPLENTY,
>     parameters: {
>       entrypoint: "stake",
>       value: 
>       {
>         stake: "10000"
>       },
>     },
>   }
> })
>
> console.log('ops', ops[0])
> try {
>     const result = await dAppClient.requestOperation({
>         operationDetails: ops as any,
>     });
>
>     console.log('result', result)
> }  catch (error) {
>   console.log(
>     `The contract call failed and the following error was returned:`,
>     error?.data[1]?.with?.string
>   );
> }
> ```

I get this error : "Parameters Invalid
Some of the parameters you provided are invalid and the request could not be completed. Please check your inputs and try again."
I assume the lines

> ```
>       value: 
>       {
>         stake: "10000"
>       },
> ```

are not correct. How can I know what parameter name I shall use? (also tried "prim" and "int")

Comment: Have you tried  `value: 10000` ? Also, the second link in your post is broken.

Comment: Or maybe `int: 10000`, or `int: "10000"`. I find the documentation of Beacon confusing. If you can find either the michelson code of the contract called here: https://docs.walletbeacon.io/guides/simple-contract-call/ or the documentation for what's given to `requestOperation` I could probably help more.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the second link. I tried several combinations of integer or string, pair or value but with no luck.

Comment: Did you try `value: { int : "10000" }` ? It seems that:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `value: { "int" : "10000" }`?

It seems that:

- the field `value` in `parameters` should be micheline (seeing how `Unit` is expressed)
- the entrypoint `%stake` has type `nat` (the linked contract says `(nat %stake)` in the parameter type)
- the Micheline encoding of the `nat` 10000 is `{"int": "10000"}`  (this can be verified by the command `$ ./tezos-client -mode mockup convert data '10000' from Michelson to json --type 'nat'`).

Comment: That would indeed make sens but I have again the same error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Could  you make a small minimal example and post it on the Beacon playground?

Comment: Also, do you know if it possible to get some debug information from the Beacon SDK. For instance, it would be interesting to see the generated RPC calls.

Comment: I added a link to a Beacon playground in the second paragraph.

Comment: If from the playground I run with Spire rather than Kukai, I have some sort of debug information including the following;
                  "kind": "temporary",
                  "id": "proto.009-PsFLoren.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
                  "location": 905,
                  "with": {
                    "string": "FA1.2_NotAllowed"

Comment: That error (`script_rejected`) is not due to a parameter of the wrong form / type being passed. Rather, the script has executed and a run-time error has occurred. I could tell you more if you give me a reference to the code of the called contract.

Comment: It is then strange that Kukai still sends the same error message as when type was wrong. Code in Michelson in available in Better Call Dev (first link in the question) but not yet in SmartPy (It probably soon will be since audit of Plenty code is now released). UI is on https://www.plentydefi.com/pools , first box.

Comment: Note: I have enough PLENTY tokens in my wallet for this request.

Comment: It is not working yet but from looking at raw JSON in [BCD](https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1QqjR4Fj9YegB37PQEqXUPHmFbhz6VJtwE/operations), I gather that I need to call "approve" first.
Regarding the syntax, no quote is needed as you can see [here](https://github.com/tzbutton/tzbutton/blob/79367d1110838bd74fa4b3956864902909f7cb4b/src/services/beacon-service.ts#L72) (not Micheline yet at that stage)

Comment: Okay, I've been playing around with your example in the Beacon playground using the Kukai wallet. Indeed, the correct way to call the stake entrypoint is through `value: { "int" : "10000" }`. regarding the quotes around "int", with or without quotes gives the same result (afaik, on the js level, `{'a':1} == {a:1}`, but json imposes the quotes). here, the contents of the field value should be the javascript representation of micheline i.e. same as the json representation but where you can put or not put quotes as you like. beacon will eventually serialize your value to json, and put in quotes.

Comment: Indeed, Beacon does not give very clear error messages (something to raise with their devs!). It gives the same error whether your value is ill-typed or whether it has just triggered a dynamic run-time error. If I run with `value: { "stake": "10000" }`  (i.e. ill-typed) I get the "invalid parameters". If I run with `value: { "int": "10000" }`  (i.e. well-typed but triggers a run-time errror) I get the "invalid parameters", but in my kukai wallet i see that a FAILWITH has been reached.

Comment: In conclusion, I think you can accept my answer, and raise the issue of clearer error messages with the beacon authors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify some of the beacon behavior.

The main responsibility of beacon is establishing and maintaining a communication channel between a dApp and a wallet. Beacon itself does **NOT** do any type checking or error handling regarding the contents of the tezos operations. The operations are sent to the other side as is, without any changes or error correction.

The beacon-sdk doesn't connect to an RPC, so it can't do any type checking on your inputs. If you want that, then you will have to use taquito, which abstracts a lot of the complexity and makes it easier to do contract calls.

After a request is received on the wallet side, the wallet takes over and processes the message. Any error that happens on the wallet side **must** be handled and displayed by the wallet. If this is not the case, an issue should be raised with the respective wallet. The beacon-sdk provides a set of error messages that can be returned to the dApp. One of them also allows the wallet to attach the error that was returned by the RPC so dApps can show some meaningful information (eg. fail with).

I will update the beacon docs, specifically the simple-contract-call page, to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.